# Polymer 1.x iron localstorage strange effect

Tags: javascript, local-storage, polymer-1.0

Hello I have this in index.html:

```
<test2-element id="storage">
    <test-element></test-element>
</test2-element>
```

My test2-element is:

```
<dom-module id="test2-element">
    <template >
        <iron-localstorage id="st" name="my-app-storage" value="{{session_user}}">
            <content></content>
        </iron-localstorage>
    </template>
    <script>
        addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
            Polymer({
                is: "test2-element",
                properties: {
                    session_user: {
                        type: Object
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And my test-emement is:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <script>
        addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            Polymer({
                is: "test-element",
                attached: function () {
                    this.async(function () {
                        console.log("Flag 1");
                        var pmn = document.querySelector('#storage');
                        console.log(pmn.get('session_user'));
                    });

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

My problem is the console is printing "Flag 1" two times. The first time the session_user is undefined but the second time the user is there from the local storage. Is this how it's supposed to work? Why is the attached callback in test-element being called two times?

Thank you

Comment: Try moving the content tag outside iron- local storage.

Comment: Then flag 1 will be printed once and the session_user will be always called before it loads.

Comment: session_user will get updated based on values from local storage.

Comment: Yeah but I need to send a request after test element loads. To get some other data and I need the session_user data. So how do I know when to send the ajax request?

Comment: I think this should have been your question to begin with. I have provided my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use mediator pattern to share the sessionUser between test2-element and test-element. You can learn more about mediator pattern in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J&index=3

Also its better to name your property to sessionUser rather than session_user. You can access the property in html as session-user.

```
<test2-element id="storage" session-user="{{sessionUser}}">
    <test-element session-user="{{sessionUser}}"></test-element>
</test2-element>
```

You can solve your problem with two different approach.

Approach 1: Listen to change in sessionUser in test-element and make the ajax call.

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <script>
        addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            Polymer({
                is: "test-element",
                properties: {
                  sessionUser: { 
                    type: Object,
                    observer: '_sessionUserChanged'
                  }
                },
                _sessionUserChanged: function(newValue) {
                  //make the ajax call here.
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Approach 2: the iron-localstroage api defines two events, 'on-iron-localstorage-load' and 'on-iron-localstorage-load-empty'. You can read more about it here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage

You can listen to these events and initiate your code.

```
<test2-element id="storage" session-user="{{sessionUser}}"
  on-iron-localstorage-load="sessionUserLoaded"
  on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="noSessionUser">
    <test-element session-user="{{sessionUser}}"></test-element>
</test2-element>
```

You can define the methods `sessionUserLoaded` and `noSessionUser` in index.html script file. You can refer to polymer starter kit to understand how to define polymer functions for elements in index.html file.

Comment: Thank you this works but only if I leave the <content> inside iron -localstorage. And the function attached is being called twice. Why is this happening? Is it a bug?

Comment: Content tag should be outside local storage. Also, the attached function is no longer required.